# How do I deploy an updated iOS Build for my app

Tags: ios, xcode, version-control, ipa

I've successfully created version 1.0.0 Build 1 for my app. I then made some updates to my code. Added, committed, pushed etc. to my GitHub branch. Then attempted to create what I called version 1.0.2 Build 2 for my app. A new .ipa file was successfully created. However it does not contain any of my updates.

So for some reason, my .ipa file isn't consistent with the updates I've pushed to my git branch.

I've now tried 50+ times and I'm not sure what to do. Please help!

[organizer build history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuwyJ.png)

Comment: you haven't given enough information. but, git has no effect on builds. whether you create a backup of your code or not doesn't change what the app does when built. Your problem has nothing to do with your version control.

Comment: @johnelemans your help is much appreciated. when I build my app and run it in a simulator through xcode, I AM seeing my updates. however when I archive and build, I'm not seeing the updates. Any ideas on what the root of my problem might be? what type of information would be useful for me provide?

Comment: show a screen shot of your organizer window with the build history showing.

Comment: @johnelemans added! I've made multiple attempts to edit my builds with Fastlane. I've used Installr instead of TestFlight. I've built an .ipa directly through xcode via Product - Archive. All builds coming out exactly the same, with none of my code updates. Newest guess is that this has something to do with me using xcode-beta "Xcode 11.2 Build version 11B44" instead of regular xcode, which has a new version 11.4.1...

Comment: make a small change to a view and see if it appears on local device.